# DLL not found by program written for XP but run on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, administrator, compatibility

I am running an application that was written for XP on a windows 7 machine.

I run the application in compatibililty Windows XP (Service Pack 3) and as administrator.

at a certain stage the application makes use of a DLL that it cant find, as seen in this picture:
[image]

what should I try next to make this work? No one else is logged onto the machine so I know the DLL is not being used.

**EDIT**

I attempted this and also received an error:

[image]

Comment: run Depends.exe and see why it fails: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx

Comment: Did you try regsvr32 again with the proper DLL name this time?

Answer (score 0):

Try manually registering the DLL:

`regsvr32 c:\progs\shopplot.dll`

Also, ensure the user the program is running as has access to that folder/file.

Comment: @karan I don't mind if you edit my typos, we are a community. ;)